# Add button to a Textbox

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I'm developing a Windows 10 UWP app and I'd like to add textboxes with buttons like shown in the screenshot. The screenshot is taken from the universal Maps app on Windows 10. If someone could point me to any documentation or samples, I'd be very grateful.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's a hint: look at the [TextBox control template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299154.aspx).

It's very long so I won't copy the whole thing, but if you look at the bottom, you'll notice that there is a ContentControl for placeholder text (PlaceholderTextContentPresenter), and there's also a button called DeleteButton which is visible when you focus on a TextBox with some text inside.

This shows you that one way to do what you want is to modify the template to have another button next to the DeleteButton or something similar (depending on what you're trying to achieve in the end) and then you can hide it or show it depending on the current VisualState, which is also something you would define in your template.

Making a template also means that you can make it quite reusable, so you should be able to use it in future projects, too.

Comment: I have a question about this solution. How to you handle the events of the extra added button? The TextBox control does not, as expected, expose such events. Would I have to subclass the TextBox or is there another way that this can be done just by retemplating the control?

Answer (score 0):

This answers the follow-up question: How do you handle the events on the extra button?

If your new button template resides in some local resource dictionary (e.g., `Page.Resources`, you can just add a click handler directly. If, however, the button template lives in a separate resource dictionary (Styles.xaml or whatever), doing so would require creating code-behind for the dictionary. It is probably better to subclass and do something like this:

```
public class MyTextBox : TextBox
{
    public event EventHandler<RoutedEventArgs> ExtraClick;

    protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        Button extraButton = GetTemplateChild("ExtraButton") as Button;
        if (extraButton != null)
        {
            extraButton.Click += (sender, e) => ExtraClick?.Invoke(sender, e);
        }
    }
}
```

You could then handle this (or any other you care to tackle) events where you actually use the button, e.g.,

```
<local:MyTextBox ExtraClick="OnExtraClicked" />
```

Code-behind:

```
private void OnExtraClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // ...
}
```

For completeness: The external dictionary must be merged into the available resources at some point, for example in the application's resources:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```